# Showing only one of several widgets in Flutter

Tags: flutter, tabs, visibility, hidden

I have a space where I to show either widget1 or widget2 (and never both). How?

In fact, widget1 to contain a simple case of retrieved information and a button to switch to show widget2 (with more information) instead.

The only solution that I came up is to use `Column(children: [widget1, widget2])` and tweak visibility of both widgets, but that's ugly. For example, there is no indication what is better `Column` or `Row`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To do this, you have multiple options:

(1) You can use conditional `spread operator` inside a column/widget

```
Column(
 children: [
   if (yourCondition == true) ...[
      const Text("Widget 1")
   ] else ...[
      const Text("Widget 2")
   ],
 ],
),
```

(2) You can use `ternary operator` inside a column/widget

```
Column(
  children: [
    yourCondition == true
      ? const Text("Widget 1")
      : const Text("Widget 2"),
   ],
),
```

(3) You can use `Visibility` widget inside a column/widget

```
Column(
  children: [
    Visibility(
      visible: yourCondition == true,
      child: const Text("Widget 1"),
    ),
    Visibility(
      visible: yourCondition == false,
      child: const Text("Widget 2"),
    ),
  ],
),
```

- For better code readability, use `ternary operator` if you have `only one condition or non-nested conditions`
- For better code readability, use conditional `spread operator` if you have `multiple conditions or nested conditions`
- Otherwise use `Visibility` widget (bur `not recommended`)

Answer (score 1):

To simply solve that, you can use a ternary operator with a widget like a container (or any that has a single child):

```
Container(
  child: condition == true 
    ? Text("Widget 1") 
    : Text("Widget 2")
)
```